# How do I evaluate if an object field moved from one specific value to another before firing?

Tags: workflowrule

I need to figure out how to evaluate in a Workflow Rule if a Case's Status WAS Solved, and then moved to Open, fire a Field Update.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(status),"Solved") && ISPICKVAL(status,"Open")
```

> And make sure Rule criteria is set as `created, and every time it's edited`.

In case you select `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria` then that formula will not compile at all.

Comment: Is there ever any danger of this type of workflow rule using up too many actions within salesforce (since it fires literally everytime a case is updated) and causing problems?

Comment: You can add other suitable logic like ISCHANGED

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `AND` and `PRIORVALUE` functions in addition to `ISPICKVAL`:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Solved'),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Open')
)
```